# How to redirect domain to path in apache server using debian 10 OS

Tags: rewrite, apache2, redirection, debian-10

I am currently using "xyzservice.abcindia.local" as a website using a reverse proxy, Now what I want to achieve is, when I hit the "xyzservice.abcindia.local"  this should redirect to "xyzservice.abcindia.com/folder1/folder2/path"  Please let me know how can I achieve the redirection, Please check below my current apache configuration.

OS: Debian 10

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
```

<VirtualHost *:443>

```
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName xyzservice.abcindia.local
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html


            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            ProxyRequests Off
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass / http://xyzservice.abcindia.local  
            ProxyPassReverse /  http://xyzservice.abcindia.local

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/test.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/test.key
```

<VirtualHost *:80>

```
            ServerName xyzservice.abcindia.local
            Redirect Permanent / https://xyzservice.abcindia.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create an HTML page and put in the root to do the redirect for you?

Please follow [this link](https://www.mySubSite.com).